# Chrome doesn't always send POST request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors, http-headers, fetch-api

I am using 'fetch' to make a post call to my node server. I am trying to do this on click of a button.

When I click the button an OPTIONS request is sent but the browser doesn't  send the subsequent POST call.

On multiple clicks, browser keeps sending Options request and just once in many attempts does Post request gets sent out.

```
let data = {name: "Butternut cucumberpatch", age: 26}
let headers = new Headers()
headers.append("Content-type", "application/json")

fetch(join(apiPath, "/user"), {
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => response)
```

(1) The code work's on my colleague's chrome browser, just not mine. The chrome version is the same. 
(2) This works perfectly fine on POSTMAN, Safari.
(3) I thought maybe there is an issue with native fetch so I tried using  'fetch', 'unfetch', 'request' modules. But still faced the same issue.

Comment: The problem is probably on the server.

Comment: Show your actual test script, including a `console.log` to demonstrate how you're getting the response. The current script wouldn't do anything with the result.

Comment: @Barmar
It works with postman. Can it still be server's issue?

Comment: What you posted is the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. Do you see the `POST` request as well in the browser?

Comment: @Barmar Not until I send the post request again a few times. The request is happening on a click event. The above post request code runs everytime I do the button click, but the post request doesn't happen until I make 3-4 attempts. Only options is sent. It's random.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when it doesn't send the POST?

Comment: @Barmar No. I don't get any errors.

Comment: I also noticed, it works fine on Safari. It send out Options request then Post request.  Doesn't work on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

Since my POST request was a cross origin request, the request preflight was happening. I changed my Content-Type to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded

If I send out the request with Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the POST request happens every time. I still don't know why it (application/json) works on my colleague's chrome browser though and not mine.
I want to make it work with application/json.